# Как правильно раздача локальный видео файлы? (Node JS + RTSP)

Tags: node.js, canvas, видео, rtsp

**Как правильно раздача патаковой видео?**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Stream = require('node-rtsp-stream');

// Streaming video with RTSP protocol
stream = new Stream({
  name: 'name',
  streamUrl: 'rtsp://127.0.0.1/:C:\Users\H4623R\Desktop\vidmo\video\file.mp4',
  wsPort: 9999,
  ffmpegOptions: {
    '-stats': '',
    '-r': 30
  }
})
```

***В этом коду я хочу раздача файл file.mp4 через протокол rtsp://*** ?

Console.log:

```js
ffmpeg version N-94619-gb29c7bcbf6 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.100 / 58. 55.100
  libavformat    58. 31.101 / 58. 31.101
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.101 /  7. 58.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
name: New WebSocket Connection (1 total)
name: New WebSocket Connection (2 total)
name: Disconnected WebSocket (1 total)
name: Disconnected WebSocket (0 total)
name: New WebSocket Connection (1 total)
```

Comment: Действительно улыбнуло)

Comment: Это не смешно ...